# Tracking Usage per API key in a multi region application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, latency, region, usage-statistics, throughput

I have an app deployed in 5 regions.

The latency between the regions varies from 150ms to 300ms

Currently, we use the method outlined in this article (usage tracking part):
http://highscalability.com/blog/2018/4/2/how-ipdata-serves-25m-api-calls-from-10-infinitely-scalable.html

But we export logs from Stackdriver to Cloud Pub/Sub. Then we use Cloud Dataflow to count the number of requests consumed per API key and update it in Mongo Atlas database which is geo-replicated in 5 regions.

In our app, we only read usage info from the nearest Mongo replica for low latency. App never updates any usage data directly in Mongo as it might incur latency cost since the data has to be updated in Master which may be in another region.

Updating API key usage counter directly from the app in Mongo doesn't seem feasible because we've traffic coming in at 10,000 RPS and due to the latency between region, I think it will run into some other issue. This is just a hunch, so far I've not tested it. I came to this conclusion based on my reading of https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/active-active-application-architectures-with-mongodb

One problem is that we end up paying for cloud pub/sub and Dataflow. Are there strategies to avoid this?

I researched on Google but didn't find how other multi-region apps keep track of usage per API key in real-time. I am not surprised, from my understanding most apps operate in a single region for simplicity and until now it was not feasible to deploy an app in multiple regions without significant overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want real-time then the best option is to go with Dataflow. You could change the way data arrives to Dataflow, for example usging `Stackdriver → Cloud Storage → Dataflow`, but instead of going though pub/sub you would go through Storage, so it’s more of a choice of convenience and comparing prices of each product cost on your use case. [Here’s](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/processing-logs-at-scale-using-dataflow) an example of how it could be with Cloud Storage.